# Conditional Probability; flipping coins

Tags: probability

Two fair coins are simultaneously flipped. This is done repeatedly until at least one of the coins comes up heads, at which point the process stops. What is the probability that the other coin also came up heads on this last flip?

**Why can't I solve this problem by doing the following PIE (where am I wrong?)**:

P(second coin is heads | first coin is heads) + P(first coin is heads | second coin is heads) - P(both coins are heads)

(1/2) + (1/2) - (1/4) = 3/4.

The correct answer is 1/3, as there are 3 possibilities {(H,T), (T,H), (H,H)}, one of which works.

Comment: I don't understand your use of conditional probabilities.  It is certainly true that inclusion-exclusion shows that the probability that at least one of the two coins is $H$ is $\frac 34$...as you say you get $\frac 12+\frac 12-\frac 14=\frac 34$.

Answer (score 1):

What is requested is a conditional probability:

$\mathbb{P}[\text{Both coins H }|\text{At Least One H }]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[(H;H)]}{\mathbb{P}[(H;H)]+\mathbb{P}[(T;H)]+\mathbb{P}[(H;T)]}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, total possible outcomes (without any conditions) when two fair coins are tossed together are $\{(H,T), (T, H), (H,H), (T,T)\}$

The number of outcomes such that at least one coin shows head are $\{(H,T), (T, H), (H,H)\}$. This is the sample space of desired event.

Now there only one outcome $(H,H)$ which shows that when one coin shows head the other coin also shows head

Therefore the probability that other coin shows head when one coin comes up with head
$$=\frac{\text{favorable outcomes}}{\text{total outcomes in sample space}}=\frac{1}{3}$$